# jQuery Hover Effects - Need help improving this code

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I created this jQuery effect where each section expands on rollover and displays new content.

http://jsfiddle.net/HWA7X/

It works fine, except when both get triggered at the same time. For example if you quickly swipe from green to blue. I'm sure there is a better way to write this. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#container-left").hover(function() {
            $('#image-right,#text-right,#text-left').fadeOut(500);
            $('#green').css({'z-index':'-2'});
            $('#container-left').animate({'width':'100%'},1000);
            $('#biz-text').fadeIn(500);

        }, function(){
            $('#image-right,#text-right,#text-left').fadeIn(500);
            $('#green').css({'z-index':'-1'});
            $('#container-left').animate({'width':'50%'},500);
            $('#biz-text').fadeOut(500);
        });


        $("#container-right").hover(function() {

            $('#image-left,#text-right,#text-left').fadeOut(500);
            $('#blue').css({'z-index':'-2'});
            $('#container-right').animate({'width':'100%','left':'0'},1000);
            $('#per-text').fadeIn(500);

        },  
           function() {
            $('#image-left,#text-right,#text-left').fadeIn(500);
            $('#blue').css({'z-index':'-1'});
            $('#container-right').animate({'width':'50%','left':'50%'},500);
            $('#per-text').fadeOut(500);

        });
```

});

UPDATE:

I added .stop() after the hover to cancel the first animation if the second one is triggered, but ideally I'd like the 2nd animation to be disabled when the 1st is running. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#container-left").hover(function() {
            $("#container-right").stop();
            $('#image-right,#text-right,#text-left').fadeOut(500);
            $('#green').css({'z-index':'-2'});
            $('#container-left').animate({'width':'100%'},1000);
            $('#biz-text').fadeIn(500);

        }, function(){
            $('#image-right,#text-right,#text-left').fadeIn(500);
            $('#green').css({'z-index':'-1'});
            $('#container-left').animate({'width':'50%'},500);
            $('#biz-text').fadeOut(500);
        });


        $("#container-right").hover(function() {
            $("#container-left").stop();
            $('#image-left,#text-right,#text-left').fadeOut(500);
            $('#blue').css({'z-index':'-2'});
            $('#container-right').animate({'width':'100%','left':'0'},1000);
            $('#per-text').fadeIn(500);

        },  
           function() {
            $('#image-left,#text-right,#text-left').fadeIn(500);
            $('#blue').css({'z-index':'-1'});
            $('#container-right').animate({'width':'50%','left':'50%'},500);
            $('#per-text').fadeOut(500);

        });
```

});

Comment: There is a plugin called as hoverintent which uses mouse hover speed to trigger the specified  behaviour. You can use that.

Comment: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: You're looking for [**stop()**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: Thank you, I added stop() and it's working better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might work aswell.

```
$("#image-left").stop( true, true );
$("#image-right").stop( true, true );
```

put the one you want to stop right after the hover.  So if hover left, make right stop.

Comment: I added .stop() without the true, true and it works. What does the true, true do?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

clearQueue & jumpToEnd by default they are false, so putting true will return as true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Seems to work better when set to false for whatever reason.

Comment: Yeah, next time you should add your code to a  JSFiddle, and give us a link to it so we can edit it live and give you better results. - are you satisfied with the results or are you still looking to expand it further?

Comment: Good call. I just put it up here: http://jsfiddle.net/HWA7X/ It's pretty good now. If it's possible I think it would work better if the 2nd animation was disable when the first one is triggered and then re-instated when it's finished. Know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

can use a global Variable
and do that

```
var active = true ;

$("#container-left").hover(function() {
     if(active)
     {
         active = false ;
         // do stuff
     }
}, function(){
     active = true ; 
     // do stuff
}

$("#container-right").hover(function() {
     if(active)
     {
         active = false ;
         // do stuff
     }
}, function(){
     active = true ; 
     // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I used .stop() as a quick fix, but I'm going to try this as well. I looks like a better way to do it.

Comment: This produces the same results as the original, but I'm curious if there's a way to make this method work. Ideally I'd like to make the other animation inactive while the first one is running, rather than stopping it once it's already running.